# max winning and losing streaks (code optimization)

Tags: php, optimization, foreach

I made this code for calculating max winning & losing streaks on an array of values. But I can get my head around doing it in one foreach loop. Currently I'm using 2  loops as follow :

```
  public function calculateStreaks()
  {
    $max_win_streak = 0;
    $_win_streak = 0;
    $max_loss_streak = 0;
    $_loss_streak = 0;

    foreach($this->all_trades_pnl as $value){
      if($value >= 0) {
        $_win_streak++;
        if($_win_streak > $max_win_streak){
          $max_win_streak = $_win_streak;
        }
      }
      else {
        $_win_streak = 0;
      }
    }
    foreach($this->all_trades_pnl as $value){
      if($value < 0) {
        $_loss_streak++;
        if($_loss_streak > $max_loss_streak) {
          $max_loss_streak = $_loss_streak;
        }
      }
      else {
        $_loss_streak = 0;
      }
    }
    return array('win_streak' => $max_win_streak, 'loss_streak' => $max_loss_streak);

  }
```

It works but seems far from optimized, any ideas to code this better ? 
Thanks a lot in advance,
Regards,
John

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since both your loop are equal i think you can mix them toghter and assign all variables at once as follow

```
public function calculateStreaks()
{
    $max_win_streak = 0;
    $_win_streak = 0;
    $max_loss_streak = 0;
    $_loss_streak = 0;

    foreach($this->all_trades_pnl as $value){
      if($value >= 0) {
        $_win_streak++;
        if($_win_streak > $max_win_streak){
          $max_win_streak = $_win_streak;
        }
        $_loss_streak = 0;
      }
      else if($value < 0) {
        $_loss_streak++;
        if($_loss_streak > $max_loss_streak) {
          $max_loss_streak = $_loss_streak;
        }
        $_win_streak = 0;
      }
    }
    return array('win_streak' => $max_win_streak, 'loss_streak' => $max_loss_streak);
}
```